# apt - run script after update using secure boot custom keys

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, apt, secure-boot

If I replace Microsofts secure boot keys with my own via the UEFI facility to add your own keys, and configure everything properly, will I need to re sign shim/kernel/etc. every time my computer updates? Is there any easy way to sign these automatically (assuming the private keys are in a specific directory at the time of the update)?

It seems like if this is the case and theres no built in facility in apt (The Debian Secure Boot CA packages come pre signed and work with shim), is there any way to run a script after an update of a particular package?

Which files would I have to re sign every time?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some context. Why would you have Microsoft keys on a Debian system?

Comment: Thats how Secure Boot works. Virtually all UEFI implementations contain microsoft keys from the factory. Microsoft has evaluated and signs shim for linux distros to easily use secure boot, but I want to remove microsoft from my chain of trust, which requires using your own keys. The context is sufficient for anyone with the ability to answer the question.

Comment: OK, don't bite! I was just worried that you might be referring to a WSL system. Not everyone has your level of knowledge, and we don't know how well an asker actually understands their situation. Don't take it personally, we get questions from all levels of expertise here.